# How to deploy React frontend and Node backend into production? (NOT Heroku)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, production-environment

I want to deploy an app which has a contact form that uses Nodemailer to send emails once the form was submitted. The frontend is in React and after submitting it sends an axios request to the backend which is in Node. While on localhost it works perfectly. Also, I've been successful in deploying the entire app to Heroku(frontend and backend) however I want to deploy this app(or rather website) to a normal hosting account with my domain name. Is it possible? Thank you in advance!

Here is my backend server in app.js.

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
require("dotenv/config")
const cors = require("cors")
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer")

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port: " + PORT);
})

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors()) 

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
  console.log("app is working");
})

app.post("/", async (req,res) => {
  console.log(("Form submittet"));
  console.log(req.body);
  const {imeiprezime,predmet,poruka} = req.body  
  try {
    const pitanje = [imeiprezime,predmet,poruka]
    console.log(pitanje);
    await res.status(201).json({pitanje})
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
      port: 587,
      secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
        user: "mislav0508@hotmail.com", 
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS, 
      },
      tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized:false
      }
    });  
    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: '"Mislav Crnkovic" <mislav0508@hotmail.com>', // sender address
      to: `mislav0508@hotmail.com`, // list of receivers
      subject: `Contact form: ${predmet}`, 
      html: `
      <p>Ime i prezime: ${imeiprezime}</p>                    
      <p>Predmet: ${predmet}</p>                    
      <p>Poruka: ${poruka}</p> 
      `, // html body
    }); 
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);   
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400)
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

Here is my frontend function in React:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()    
    if(data.imeiprezime && data.predmet && data.poruka){
      await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/", data) //change URI when deploying app.
      .then((result) => {
        const pitanje = result.data.pitanje
        console.log(pitanje);
        alert("Hvala vam na upitu!")        
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))    
      setData({imeiprezime:"",predmet:"",poruka:""})      
    }else{
      console.log("please fill out required fields");
      alert("Molimo popunite sva polja")
    }
  }
```

Comment: I  hope that by `normal hosting account` you mean your own server or VPS where you have full controll of the operating system. If so then you should have a look at nginx. Nginx allows you to proxy the requests to your app. You also need to point DNS records to your server's IP. There are tons of tutorials all over the web. Also this question is not a good question for StackOverflow since you don't seem to have any problem with your code.

Comment: Take a look at CORS problem. In order to verify that this is the problem, look at the console when the axios is calling the Node, maybe it will help you figure it out

Comment: @Mislav You should understand package.json file(scripts). I suggest that you take a look of one of the MERN courses.